# What is the German equivalent of the English "aka"?

Tags: translation, expression

In English, the abbreviation aka means "also known as".

A literal German translation might be "auch bekannt wie". Is this, in fact, the correct German equivalent? And is the abbreviation *ABW* (or the correct one) in common use?

Comment: ABW ist nicht nur nicht gebräuchlich, es ist falsch, denn wenn, dann würde man `auch bekannt als` sagen, nicht `wie`. Und dann würde man die Abkürzung nicht groß schreiben, sondern so, wie das Abgekürzte (`s.o.`, `d.h.`, `etc.`).

Comment: As @userunknown saied in german, "ABW" is not correct. It has to be "auch bekannt als" (not "wie") and would not be written with capital letters. "aba." would be possible but is not common. [Apparently](https://abkuerzungen.woxikon.de/abkuerzung/aba.php), ABA has the defined meanind "Abfallbehandlungsanlage " though it is not commonly known. But in modern German, you can literally uses aka. most Germans understand "Globish" terms like this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The direct translation is "auch bekannt als". Alternatively you can use "alias".

I'm not aware of any common abbreviations for either of those (then again "alias" is usually short enough).

Note that ["alias"](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/alias) is often used as an adverb (sample from Wiktionary):

> Diesen Text verfasste Kurt Tucholsky *alias* Peter Panter.

But [Alias can also be a noun](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Alias#):

> Mein *Alias* beim deutschsprachigen Wiktionary heißt „xyz“.

Comment: "Alias" qualifies as an "abbreviation" in my book.

Comment: Alias is an abbreviation? Of what?

Comment: :I put "abbreviation" in quotes to mean "short version," not a literal abbreviation.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. You probably meant what I wrote as '"alias" is usually short enough'.

Comment: Das ist ganz richtig.

Answer (score 19):

In case there is not a reference to a person's name (like in the case of an artist name) we can also use ["*oder*"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/oder#Bedeutung1e) for this purpose:

> Ein Parasol oder Schirmpilz ist eine Delikatesse.

To avoid confusion "*auch*" may be added:

> Ein Parasol oder auch Schirmpilz ist eine Delikatesse.

Answer (score 12):

The literal translation would be "Meier, auch bekannt als Müller" or "Meier, auch bekannt unter dem Namen Müller" or "Meier, genannt Müller".

You could also say "Meier alias Müller", but that often implies a cover name with misleading intent, such as for spies.

In case of a woman who has adopted her husband's name, you would say "Meier, geb./geborene Müller"

Except for the "geb.", I am not aware of an acronym or abbreviation for this.

Comment: Are you sure, "aka" can be used in the sense of "geborene"? I thought this is (only) "née".

Comment: @musiKk Thats a question for english.SE…

Comment: @feeela: Well, the answer to my question decides whether Hackworth's answer is appropriate or not (at least the second half). But I see, this is just going to be one of those discussions again, so I might as well shut up now.

Comment: I think Hackworth wasn't saying that _geborene_ may be used as translation for _aka_, it's just another example of how to say a person may be known under a different name. I'm no native English-speaker, so it's difficult for me to answer your question, but I would say that [geborene **can't** be translated to aka](http://dict.leo.org/?search=geborene).

Comment: It often implies a cover name, if it is a cover name - it only depends on the context. And even artist names are of course used to mislead in the one or the other sense; to protect privacy, or to have a better sounding marketing instrument. Only Nicknames like 'Frank, auch bekannt als "der Dicke"' would be an exception, but 'Frank, alias: "der Dicke"' is fine - isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answers above, there is also "auch genannt", as in "Das ist Josef, auch genannt 'Joe'".

Answer (score 3):

The nearest equivalent in the sense of shortness would probably be simply "auch".

Example:

> Der Puma (auch: Berglöwe) ist eine Katzenart Nord-, Mittel- und
>   Südamerikas.

In this context, "auch" is commonly used as a short form of "auch bekannt als" or "auch genannt". In this sense, I would guess it is the nearest equivalent of "aka" as a short form of "also known as".

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the <s>context</s> people you are talking to, you can also use "aka". Of course not in official papers or something like that. But in a colloquial way <s>most</s> younger / technical interested people should understand it.

Comment: Meine Eltern würde "aka" ganz sicher nicht verstehen. Mein Neffe und meine Nichte, die mit Französisch i.d. Schule begonnen haben, sicher auch nicht. Nur weil viele Deutsche "railway station" verstehen wird daraus nicht ein dt. Wort.

Comment: I certainly read "aka" in internet forums, but I never would use this in a spoken conversation, because I would not know how to pronounce it: "ah-ka-ah"? Sounds a little bit stupid to me and doesn't roll off the tongue easily. "ah-ka"? This will me (mis-)understood as "AK" (Arbeitskreis? Awtomat Kalaschnikowa?).

Comment: @userunknown: Deshalb ja auch "depending on the context". Es steht da auch nirgends, dass es ein deutsches Wort ist, nur weil es Leute verstehen oder benutzen.

Comment: @Feroc: Die Frage lautet, was ein dt. Äquivaltent ist. `aka` ist offensichtlich keins. Es hängt auch nicht vom Kontext ab, sondern von den Adressaten, ob diese `aka` verstehen. Leute unter 40 mit Englischausbildung, die den ganzen Tag auf englischsprachigen Blogs rumhängen - sicher. Ich sage Dir: Die meisten Leute verstehen es nicht. Die meisten Leute können nämlich nicht gut Englisch. Und wenn sie es 10x verstehen wird es kein äquivalentes dt. Wort, und damit wäre Deine Antwort besser nur ein Kommentar.

Comment: @userunknown: Bei einem entsprechenden Context hast du auch die entsprechenden Adressaten. Damit ist es dann wieder vollkommen egal ist, was die "meisten" verstehen. Hier geht es um die Deutsche Sprache und wie man sie nutzt. Wenn jemand nach einem deutschen Wort sucht, dann halte ich es für eine passende Antwort, dass man nicht für jeden Fall eine Übersetzung benötigt. Wenn es dir nicht gefällt, dann darfst du gerne die entsprechenden Links unter dem Beitrag betätigen.

Comment: @Feroc: Ich muss hier user unknown insofern zustimmen, dass ich auch glaube dass "aka" von einer großen Mehrheit aller Menschen in Deutschland nicht verstanden wird. Innerhalb meiner peer group dagegen hättest du recht: da wird es eine Mehrheit sein, diese Menschen sind im Schnitt jünger und beherrschen Englischen Netzslang. Ich mache häufiger den Fehler, mein unmittelbares Umfeld als Maßstab für alle Menschen zu nehmen, vielleicht ist dir das hier auch passiert. Deine Antwort würde von einer Ergänzung in die Richtung profitieren, finde ich.

Comment: Quälgeister... Antwort etwas angepasst. ;)

Comment: Qualitätsgeist schreibt man auch anders ;) - IMHO this is still not an answer to the question, but a comment.

Comment: Allgemein kann man wohl sagen, dass "aka" dort verstanden wird, wo auch "IMHO" und "AFAIK" verstanden werden.

Comment: Also, ich kenne "a-ka-a" in dieser Aussprachevariante aus Zeiten, wo ich noch kein Internet hatte, aber vielleicht war das eine regionale Sache. Und zu den Kommentaren a la "auch wenn es alle verstehen, ist es noch lang kein deutsches Wort": Doch, dann ist es auf gutem Wege eins zu werden, so entstehen nunmal Fremdwörter. Und jetzt bitte keine Diskussion, ob Fremdwörter deutsche Wörter sind oder nicht, wer möchte hier ernsthaft anzweifeln, dass z.B. Orange ein deutsches Wort ist?

Comment: @fifaltra: Ist "Merci" ein deutsches Wort?